# Padded batches does not handle the last batch of the data with smaller size than batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset where I have images and per image I have 10 questions and thus 10 answers. I have successfully trained and checkpointed the model. The model consists of two inputs, one input as image to a CNN and the other input as question to the LSTM. So for every image I would feed in 10 questions. The results of both would then be concatenated and input to the FC layers.

Considering I have a batch size of 64, I would feed in 64 images and 640 questions. At the time of concatenation I would need to have the dimension at `axis:0` to be equal, to avoid concatenation error due to different dimensions. Thus, I flatten my CNN network output and repeat it 10 times and then concatenate it to the LSTM output.

Inside the **model_rn.py**, I do following:

```py
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.img = tf.placeholder(
            name='img',
            dtype=tf.float32,
            shape=[self.batch_size, self.img_size, self.img_size, 3]
        )
        self.q = tf.placeholder(
            name='ques',
            dtype=tf.float32,
            shape=[self.batch_size * 10, self.ques_dim]
        )
        self.ans = tf.placeholder(
            name='ans',
            dtype=tf.float32,
            shape=[self.batch_size * 10, self.ans_dim]
        )
        # and some more class variables
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        def cnn(img, q, scope):
            # some Conv2D and BatchNormalization
            flat = Flatten(name='flatten')(bn_4)  # layer where data is flattened before concatenate
            flat = tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(flat, 10, axis=0)  # repeat 10 times
        # some statements to feed data into LSTM and CNN
```

Then I load my model and try to run it on the test dataset which contains 20 images, 200 questions and thus 200 answers. But then I get the error:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (20, 128, 128, 3) for Tensor 'img_1:0', which has shape '(640, 128, 128, 3)'

To feed the batches from the test dataset I have used `padded_batch`.

```py
dataset_img = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images)).padded_batch(
    64, padded_shapes=(128, 128, 3)
)
dataset_ques = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((questions)).padded_batch(
    64 * 10, padded_shapes=(14)
)
dataset_ans = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((answers)).padded_batch(
    64 * 10, padded_shapes=(22)
)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have constrained your placeholder to take exactly "batch_size" number of rows. To take any rows you can create placeholder like this

```py
self.img = tf.placeholder(
            name='img',
            dtype=tf.float32,
            shape=[None, self.img_size, self.img_size, 3]
        )
```

similarly for self.q and self.ans